# Match media not working

Tags: javascript

I've following match media code and its not working as expected.

```
var handleMatchMedia=function(mediaQuery){
  if(mediaQuery.matches){
    $("p").text("it matches"); 
}else{
       $("p").text("doesn't match"); 
}},
    mql=window.matchMeida('(min-width:700)');
handleMatchMedia(mql);
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
```

Link to the code
http://jsfiddle.net/C9dJZ/1/

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo.

```
window.matchMeida('(min-width:700)');
```

should be

```
window.matchMedia('(min-width:700)');
```

Comment: Should be closed as a typo :)

Comment: I missed that out. thanx. :D

Comment: Am i going crazy? I don't see the typo...And this answer has the same code snippet twice...

Comment: @EmmaEarlKent Meida Media :)